# Javascript code executed on JavaFX WebEngine in second Thread

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, javafx, webengine

I have a question. Is possible to execute javascript code on WebEngine in second Thread without using Platform.runlater()? Excuting javascript code in main Thread freezes my app, so i want to run it in second Thread, but it looks that it works like other controlls in JavaFX - it must be in main Thread. Its any option to bypass it?
Regards

Comment: Maybe you should focus on making JS that does not freeze - Please show the JS you want to execute against the WebView

Comment: I placed Youtube player in WebView, and i want to control it using javascript methods (Youtube iFrame API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#). it looks like: https://scr.hu/Y7aVDW, https://scr.hu/dJWry1. It works fine, but when internet connection is low or when I lost connection those methods freezes application. Any idea how prevent it?